# Slight problem with Google Finance API

Tags: google-finance-api

Hello all I can't seem to log in with google finance api to my account and I don't know why. Here is my code

```
public static void main (String [ ] args)

 {
  FinanceService myService = new FinanceService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
  try
  {
   myService.setUserCredentials("...@gmail.com","...");
  }
  catch (AuthenticationException e)
  {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

And here is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at com.google.gdata.util.VersionRegistry.ensureRegistry(VersionRegistry.java:88)
 at com.google.gdata.client.Service.initServiceVersion(Service.java:458)
 at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:147)
 at main.main(main.java:55)
```

line 55 is the one that starts out FinanceService

Comment: If that was your password I suggest you change it immediately. Do not post personal details on this site.

Comment: Nah man just an old placeholder thanks for the concern though. That'd be a pretty week password.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of reddit: christophermaness.com/a-problem-with-compiling-a-java-project –